# Python как нажимать на кнопку в браузере без selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, browsers

Мне нужно открыть 2-4 браузера одновременно и зайти на сайт для проверки cps однако при использовании selenium cps очень маленький подскажите пожалуйста что делать?
P.s: желательно использовать firefox или opera(обычную)

Comment: Requests, urllib и тд не подходит

Comment: можно использовать os+opencv

Comment: Clark Devlin мне нужно чтобы 2-4 браузера работало одновременно

Comment: @Mario экран большой - 4 поместятся окошка)

Comment: eri, а как нажимать одновременно?